# CPU load affecting power adapter on HP ProBook 4510a

Tags: power-management, hp, battery, acpi

The battery on my HP Probook 4510a is taking a long time to charge - currently 3% per day.  it's got a proprietary battery and charger, and I'd like to know what terminal commands I can use to determine whether (if) the battery or the charger is at fault.

I'd really rather use Terminal than Gui, because the laptop is quite slow , I am guessing because of the critical power ( currently at 15%)  The laptop had Windows on it and I blitzed it and put Lubuntu on it, and it has been slow to operate and charge under both OS es, so I am guessing it's a hardware problem.

Specifications:

- HP Probook 4510a
- Intel Core Duo TS 5870
- 2GB RAM
- ATA Hitachi HTSS4502 hard drive

  Ubuntu 14.04 64bit with Linux 4.4.0-31-lowlatency on USD

  [output of htop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZWjt.png)

  vidal@USD:~$ cat /proc/interrupts
             CPU0       CPU1
    0:     241524     241065   IO-APIC   2-edge      timer
    1:        548        553   IO-APIC   1-edge      i8042
    8:          1          0   IO-APIC   8-edge      rtc0
    9:      25284      25525   IO-APIC   9-fasteoi   acpi
   12:     103832     104172   IO-APIC  12-edge      i8042
   16:         57         63   IO-APIC  16-fasteoi   uhci_hcd:usb3
   17:          0          0   IO-APIC  17-fasteoi   uhci_hcd:usb4, wlan0
   18:          0          0   IO-APIC  18-fasteoi   uhci_hcd:usb5 uhci_hcd:usb8
   19:         18         13   IO-APIC  19-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb1
   20:          0          0   IO-APIC  20-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb2,       uhci_hcd:usb6
   22:          0          0   IO-APIC  22-fasteoi   uhci_hcd:usb7
   23:          0          0   IO-APIC  23-edge      lis3lv02d
   24:          0          0   PCI-MSI 458752-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
   25:          0          0   PCI-MSI 460800-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
   26:          0          0   PCI-MSI 462848-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
   27:          0          0   PCI-MSI 466944-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
   28:          0          0   PCI-MSI 468992-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
   29:       4823         37   PCI-MSI 69730304-edge      eth0
   30:      37919      37995   PCI-MSI 512000-edge      0000:00:1f.2
   31:        205        203   PCI-MSI 32768-edge      i915
   32:        265        259   PCI-MSI 442368-edge      snd_hda_intel
  NMI:        670        649   Non-maskable interrupts
  LOC:   15476100   15735200   Local timer interrupts
  SPU:          0          0   Spurious interrupts
  PMI:        670        649   Performance monitoring interrupts
  IWI:          0          7   IRQ work interrupts
  RTR:          0          0   APIC ICR read retries
  RES:    1620610    1602688   Rescheduling interrupts
  CAL:        495        552   Function call interrupts
  TLB:       9674       5350   TLB shootdowns
  TRM:          0          0   Thermal event interrupts
  THR:          0          0   Threshold APIC interrupts
  DFR:          0          0   Deferred Error APIC interrupts
  MCE:          0          0   Machine check exceptions
  MCP:         55         55   Machine check polls
  ERR:          0
  MIS:          0
  PIN:          0          0   Posted-interrupt notification event
  PIW:          0          0   Posted-interrupt wakeup event

Comment: UPDATE:  I just figured out that, when the (proprietary) power adapter is not  plugged in the machine runs fine, but the battery discharges veeery quickly.  so I guess I am trying to figure out battery and adapter diagnostic tools for Ubuntu at the command line.

Comment: UPDATE:  Blitzed the machine, put Ubuntu Studio on it ( which is the OS I actually want to use because of reasons ) .Got the battery up to 25% and the machine is working like a charm on battery.  when I plug the adaptor back in, everything slows down again ( albeit less so ) .  It's like the machine is just busy doing...something.  But NOT charging in a hurry and adding a 2 second wait between each click.  I found the commands htop and glances which  gave the results above.